# integer with all digits, multiple of 126

Tags: divisibility

> Find a positive integer containing all ten digits: $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ that is a multiple of $126$

I don't really know where to start. I guess I could find the prime factorization of $126$, which is $2*3^2*7$, but I don't know how that helps. The only thing I can think of is just multiplying the number, but that would take forever.

Comment: Hint:  the sum of those digits is $45$ which is divisible by $9$...hence any $10$ digit number made by permuting them will be divisible by $9$.  It's easy to make the number divisible by $2$, so your only problem is $7$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a number containing all the digits $\ 0,1,2,\cdots,9\ $ exactly once is divisble by $9$, we only have to make sure that the number is even and divisible by $7$.

Since the numbers $\ 91,56,203,84,7\ $ are divisible by $7$, the number

$$9156203784$$ must be divisible by $7$ and hence must be divisble by $126$.

Comment: How do you find the numbers $91,56,203,84$? I know why you use them, but I don't know how to get them from $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$

Comment: I started with $91$ and $56$ and had the luck that the rest worked :)

Comment: how do i find it if I'm out of luck? ;)

Comment: Start with , for example, $1234567890$ and begin to permut the last two digits, the last three digits and so on You will be successful with $1234567908$.

Answer (score 1):

You said a positive integer, **not the smaller positive integer**. You said also that is must contain each integer, **not** that it must contain each integer **once**.

Then I have a solution in the pocket

Take $1234567890000$ , compute its modulo $126$ and the difference of the latter with $126$ and you find $108$. Then just add them and deliver your result :  **$1234567890108$**

If it is not a valid answer, I'm sorry for the trick. Let's always be careful with the statements :)

Comment: I guess I can do that without a calculator, but it might be hard

Comment: @Anonymous : I did the division with my phone, with the calc windows utility and with my old pen : all render 108 for  1234567890000-floor(1234567890000/126) ... It is probably the solution expected by the teacher :)